# Blank ListView in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-listview, adapter

I'm making a parse json app and i've got an issue !

I've got these codes :

Temps.java :

```
package model;

public class Temps {
private String direction;
private String ligne;
private String temps;

public Temps() {
}

public Temps(String direction, String ligne, String temps) {

    this.direction = direction;

    this.ligne = ligne;

    this.temps = temps;
}


public String getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

public void setDirection(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.direction = thumbnailUrl;
}


public String getTemps() {
    return temps;
}

public void setTemps(String temps) {
    this.temps = temps;
}

public String getLigne() {
    return ligne;
}

public void setLigne(String ligne) {
    this.ligne = ligne;
}

}
```

TempsActivity.java :

```
package activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.CustomListAdapterTemps;
import app.AppController;
import model.Temps;


 public class TempsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url

private List<Temps> directionList = new ArrayList<Temps>();
private ListView listView2;
private CustomListAdapterTemps adapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
private Menu menu;
private MenuInflater inflater;
HashMap<String, String> lieumap = new HashMap<String, String>();


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_temps, container, false);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;


}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String url = "https://open.tan.fr/ewp/tempsattente.json/" + intent.getExtras().getString("text") + " ";
    System.out.println(intent.getExtras().getString("text") + " Test Test ");


    listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_temps);

    // movieList is an empty array at this point.
    adapter = new CustomListAdapterTemps(getParent(), directionList);
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request


    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Rechargement...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = null;
                                    try {
                                        obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    Temps temps = new Temps();

                                    temps.setDirection(obj.getString("terminus"));

                                    temps.setLigne(obj.getString("sens"));


                                    temps.setTemps(obj.getString("temps"));


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }


            });


            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);


        }
    });
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);


   }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new ArretsFragment();
        title = "Rechercher";

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temps);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String url = "https://open.tan.fr/ewp/tempsattente.json/" + intent.getExtras().getString("text") + " ";


    listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_temps);

    // movieList is an empty array at this point.
    adapter = new CustomListAdapterTemps(this, directionList);
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);

    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = null;
                            try {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Temps temps = new Temps();
                            temps.setDirection(obj.getString("terminus"));
                            temps.setLigne(obj.getString("sens"));
                            temps.setTemps(obj.getString("temps"));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);


}


}
```

And CustomListViewAdapterTemps.java :

```
package adapter;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.example.pierre.tan.R;

import java.util.List;

import app.AppController;
import model.Temps;


public class CustomListAdapterTemps extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Temps> directionItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


public CustomListAdapterTemps(Activity activity, List<Temps> directionItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.directionItems = directionItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return directionItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return directionItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rowtemps, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView direction = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.direction);
    TextView ligne = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ligne);
    TextView temps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temps);


    // getting movie data for the row
    Temps m = directionItems.get(position);


    // title
    direction.setText(m.getDirection());


    ligne.setText(m.getLigne());

    temps.setText(m.getTemps());

    return convertView;


}


}
```

I don't understand why I get a Blank ListView because the url json work and in the console we can see just the json Request with the data. If someone can help me it would be very nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your **directionList** is empty. In your loops, where you parse JSON, you're creating your **Temps** object:

```
Temps temps = new Temps();
temps.setDirection(obj.getString("terminus"));
temps.setLigne(obj.getString("sens"));
temps.setTemps(obj.getString("temps"));
```

but you're not adding them to your **directionsList**. Add this line just after the above:

```
directionList.add(temps);
```

Comment: Thank's it was simple but I forgot quickly this type of things :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think that you are not adding your response to the list, please try this:

```
   Temps temps = new Temps();
   temps.setDirection(obj.getString("terminus"));
   temps.setLigne(obj.getString("sens"));
   temps.setTemps(obj.getString("temps"));

   directionList.add(temps);
```